# full krylov subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A$ be any matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}$, let $v_0$ be any nonzero vector in $\mathbb{C}^N$, and let $\mathcal{G}_0$ be the full krylov space $\mathcal{K}_N(A,v_0)$.

I don't know why $\mathcal{G}_0$ is invariant subspace of $A$.

Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

$$K_N(A,v_0) = span(v_0,Av_0,A^2v_0,....A^{N-1}v_0)$$Now we have two cases either all the vectors($v_0,Av_0...A^{N-1}v_0$) are independent or they are not independent. If they are all independent then $K_n(A,v_0)$ spans the whole space $C^N$ and hence invariant trivially. If they are not independent there exist some $i$ such that $A^iv_0$ can be written as the linear combination of $v_0,Av_0,A^2v_0...A^{i-1}v_0$. And moreover because of this for any $j>=i, A^jv_0$ is in the span of $v_0,Av_0,A^2v_0...A^{i-1}v_0$, which makes $K_N(A,v_0)$ invariant subspace of $A$.